# Is 'off' equal to '!on' ? in htaccess syntaxe?

Tags: .htaccess

Are the next two codes equivalent?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!**

> HTTPS
>       Will contain the text "on" if the connection is using SSL/TLS, or "off" otherwise. (This variable can be safely used regardless of
>   whether or not mod_ssl is loaded).
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

The exclamation mark `!` specifies a negative match, so the rule is only applied if HTTPS does not contain "on".

Comment: Thanks, Croises! My knowledge of htaccess is zero.